# Как парсить параметры HTTP запроса?

Tags: delphi, http, indy

Мне на сервер `TIdHTTPServer` приходит запрос с параметрами `ARequestInfo.Params.Text` в таком формате:

```
item[0][value1]=value
item[0][value2]=value
item[0][value3]=value
item[1][value1]=value
item[1][value2]=value
item[1][value3]=value
...
item[n][value1]=value
item[n][value2]=value
item[n][value3]=value
```

Подскажите, как работать в цикле с такими параметрами, если заранее не известно **N**?

**UPD**

Узнаю количество так

```
i := 0;
while ARequestInfo.Params.Values['item[' + IntToStr(i) + '][value1]'] <> '' do
begin
    Inc(i);
end;
```

**i** равно количеству экземпляров.

Comment: В Делфе нету оператора `&`, уточните пожалуйста, что у вас там на самом деле? Или это прям дословное содержимое?

Comment: @Kromster вы правы, исправил в вопросе. суть дела не меняется, мне приходят параметры в неизвестном мне количестве, как можно узнать сколько их?

Comment: Так а  `item` и `value` вы откуда берете? Если `ARequestInfo.Params.Text` это просто текст с параметрами, то их число равно количеству `&` в строке +1, не так ли?

Comment: @Kromster нет, там есть и другие параметры и эти в том числе, имена item и valueX всегда стандартное, но количество экземпляров value1-value3 не известно

Comment: Если число параметров не передается, то вы в принципе правильно делаете - `while .. do`

Comment: Можете показать пример запроса который вы обрабатываете?